# What's wrong my ajax post on Rails using partial js.slim template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, slim-lang

I' making an Rails application like a comments board and I'd like to use ajax on it. However, my code doesn't work and I cannot understand the cause at all...

Here is my controller code.

```
# controller/article_controller.rb

def show
  @comments = Comment.where(article_id:params[:id])
end

def comment
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      @comments = Comment.where(article_id:params[:id])
      format.js
    else
      render 'show'
    end
  end
end

private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
  end
```

and view is

```
views/article/show.slim

= form_for(@comment, url: comment_path, data: { remote: true }) do |f|
    = f.text_area :comment
    = f.submit 'create'

#board_comments
  = render partial: 'comment', locals: { comments: @comments }
```

partial template is
    views/article/_comment.slim

```
- comments.try(:each) do |comment|
  p = comment[:comment]
```

and views/article/comment.js.slim template is this.

```
| $('#board_comments').html("#{j render(partial: 'article/comment', locals: { comments: @comment }) }");
| $('#comment_comment').val('');
```

What's the wrong point on my code?

Logs are

```
Started POST "/article/9/comment" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 00:31:05 +0900
Processing by ArticleController#comment as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FJYVadfpYoZc7OPdk68guKxiPLKdYb2LkQJfKVKRZw=", "comment"=>{"comment"=>"1234"}, "commit"=>"create", "id"=>"9"}
(0.5ms)  BEGIN
SQL (6.3ms)  INSERT INTO `comments` (`comment`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`, `article_id`) VALUES ('1234', '2014-08-03 15:31:05', '2014-08-03 15:31:05', 1, 9)
(2.2ms)  COMMIT
Comment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments`  WHERE `comments`.`article_id` = 9
Rendered article/_comment.slim (1.0ms)
Rendered article/comment.js.slim within layouts/application (38.0ms)
Rendered shared/_menu.html.slim (1.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_ga.slim (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 213ms (Views: 159.1ms | ActiveRecord: 9.5ms)
```

views/layouts/application.slim

```
doctype html
html
  head
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = favicon_link_tag('favicon.ico')
    = csrf_meta_tags

  body
    = render 'shared/menu'
    = yield
    = render 'layouts/ga'
```

Comment: rails log just return 200

Rendered article/_comment.slim (57.3ms)                                                                                            Rendered article/comment.js.slim within layouts/application (91.6ms)
Rendered shared/_menu.html.slim (1.9ms)                                                                               Rendered layouts/_ga.slim (0.4ms)                                                                             Completed 200 OK in 267ms (Views: 223.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)

Comment: can you post your logs from terminal when you submit your form? Also post your comment_params method

Comment: sorry, I couldn't your comment.
`
Rendered article/_comment.slim (57.3ms) Rendered article/comment.js.slim within layouts/application (91.6ms) Rendered shared/_menu.html.slim (1.9ms) Rendered layouts/_ga.slim (0.4ms) Completed 200 OK in 267ms (Views: 223.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms) 
`

Comment: def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
    end

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this line in your views/article/comment.js.slim

```
$('#board_comments').html("#{j render(partial: 'article/comment', locals: { comments: @comment }) }");
```

**You are passing @comment as comments in your partial** and your partial contains

```
- comments.try(:each) do |comment|
  p = comment[:comment]
```

But according to this line `locals: { comments: @comment }` *comments only contain newly created comment and not all the comments* so you need to change your js.slim file to this

```
$('#board_comments').html("#{j render(partial: 'article/comment', locals: { comments: @comments }) }"); // notice its @comments not @comment
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! and I tried to change but it still doesn't work... Logs are also same just response 200.

Comment: @kei i think the logs you posted are from browsers console. Can you edit your question and post your full logs from terminal? Need to see whats happening when you submit your form

Comment: I post my full logs which create when I submit from form.

Comment: @kei looking at your logs your comment is being created successfully so there is something wrong with js. Can you use a simple `alert("working");` at top of your js.slim file just to see if that works

Comment: Actually, Nothing happen.. I also thought the problem is in js.. but how should I know the point?

Comment: @kei do you have jquery included in your app? try alert from your browsers console. If it doesn't work then there is no jquery in your app. Also post your layout file

Comment: yes, in assets/javascripts/application.js, I wrote it like this `//= require jquery` and on the other part, I use jquery like $.ajax().

Comment: And When I type the second code on js.slim from console($('#comment_comment').val('');), It works well.

Comment: @kei but a simple alert isn't working from your js.slim file and what you mean by `I use jquery like $.ajax()`. Can you post your layout file?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean on other js, I use jquery syntax and it works well. and I tried just `console.log('hoge');` on js.slim and also it does'nt work. Does it mean the js.slim file didn't read? because console.log is just javascript syntax.

Comment: @kei looking at your console `Rendered article/comment.js.slim within layouts/application (38.0ms)` so it did render. Can you post your layout file? :)

Comment: Added the layouts/application.slim on the first post!

Comment: @kei so you do have javascript include tag. Just wanted to confirm. What do you see in your browsers console when you submit ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

If you still need an answer, or in case somebody will suffer the same.
I've just asked [close question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142099/rails-code-for-format-js-do-not-work/40143534#40143534), and the solution was to add `{ render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }` after the `format.js`